# Does the GTX 970 supports two 4K monitors at 60Hz?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, 4k-resolution

I have one Dell P2715Q 4K monitor and I'm planning to buy a second one, will my GTX 970 be able to handle both of them at 4K60Hz?

I'm not planning to game in this machine, I'll used primarily for software development and video editing in Premiere on Windows 10 Pro.

I'm currently using the display port to connect the current monitor and plan to use the HDMI cable for the second, since according to Dell the newer units of this monitor comes with HDMI 2.0 support even though only HDMI 1.4 is enabled in the factory.

Comment: ooh, how do you get HDMI 2.0 ? I have an older unit. Firmware upgrade?

Comment: It's a hidden setting in the menu, only available to units sold after February 2016. You can read more here https://www.dell.com/support/article/br/pt/brdhs1/sln306595/setting-up-p2415q--p2715q-monitors-with-hdmi-20-support-4k-x-2k-60hz?lang=en

Comment: Nvidia has published the specifications for the GTX 970 on their website.  What does that specification indicate is the maximum resolution

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpA4z.jpg so the maximum resolution across 2 4K would be supported

Comment: @Ramhound are you referring to the maximum digital resolution? I never understood this item, the value of 5120x3200 pixels is per monitor or the sum of all 4 digital ports?

Comment: @holiveira It’s the maximum resolution across all monitors